# LinkedIn offsite sharing link not working on mobile?

Tags: linkedin-api

Using the offsite LinkedIn sharing code, i.e. [https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=%7Burl%7D), and it's not working on mobile.

It works perfectly fine on desktop, but mobile users are either taken to the LinkedIn home page with no option to share, or they get a messages that says, "This feature only available in our app" with an Open In App button. When they click the button, they are taken to the app store.

Answer (score 7):

Try using this link(I use this, and it do not ask to open or download the LinkedIn app) --- `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={url}`
[Click here](https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://bing.com) to test [bing.com](https://www.bing.com) on LinkedIn.

Comment: Glad, it helped :)

Comment: Your example 'Click here' is not working for me.. None of the urls I tried with worked :(  This is the problem I'm having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71614050/linkedin-share-url-error-destructure-property-manager-of-e-as-it-is-null  Does anybody know what can be wrong?

Comment: From your comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71614050/linkedin-share-url-error-destructure-property-manager-of-e-as-it-is-null#71618472), it seems like your issue is solved now.