# Linkedin share URL error: destructure property 'manager' of 'e' as it is null

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to share an url using linkedin share url like below.

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flinkedin.com

I got the error below:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'manager' of 'e' as it is null.`

Regards, Flavio

Comment: Having the same problem here!! I used the inspector to check my url (https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.iansresearch.com%2Fciso-comp-survey%2F) and the url is fine. But I keep getting the same error from linkedin :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that LinkedIn have broken this functionality, as the behavior is widespread across popular sites, but of course they haven't acknowledged that anywhere and its pretty much impossible to get in touch with support team. Hopefully they clear this up soon.

Comment: It now seems to be fixed! –